# Powershell "select -First 0" behaviour

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Can anyone explain what's occurring in the case of `select -first 0` example in the code below?

```
Function Test-Example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    process {
        $global:x++
        write-verbose 'I''m running!'
        $InputObject
    }
}

[int]$global:x = 0 #reset the counter
1..100 | Test-Example -Verbose | select -first 10
$global:x #outputs 10

$global:x = 0 #reset the counter
1..100 | Test-Example | select -first 1000
$global:x #outputs 100; as we only iterate 100 times depsite asking for the first 1000

$global:x = 0 #reset the counter
1..100 | Test-Example | select -first 0 
$global:x #outputs 100; which doesn't make sense since we don't see any output, suggesting `select -first 0` behaves like `select * | out-null`.
```

If we add the -verbose switch we see that the value of `$global:x` matches the number of iterations according to the verbose output (i.e. we get 10 verbose messages in the first example, 100 in the second, and 100 in the third).

Comment: Your function doesn't handle pipe cancelation so it processes the entire input. This a guess though.

Comment: [This article on pipe cancellation](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powershell_com_featured_blogs/b/tobias/posts/cancelling-a-pipeline) should be helpful.

Comment: [Pipeline stop condition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2017-06-10%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/select-object.cs#L216) says: `_first != 0`. Thus, pipeline is not stopping, when you specify `-First 0`.

Comment: Thanks guys; interesting reading on pipe cancellation.  If I've understood: the only way to cancel the upstream commands is to break out of the current code; which requires something outside of the pipeline to break from or catch the exception.

Comment: Thanks also to @PetSerAl for the link to the code / culprit.  It seems that by writing this in C# the pipe cancellation limitation isn't an issue there (i.e. doesn't require that anyone using `select-object -first` include code around that statement to break from or catch any exceptions), so the question remains, why would MS explicitly say `_first != 0` in that condition (unless that's an oversight, since `-first 0` is an odd use case; though is allowed according to the ValidateRange, so should be supported.

Comment: My guess is that by the time this code's reached, the previous statements in the pipeline have already executed for the first item; so there is no logical way to stop that.  (i.e. in my code above, `$global:x` would have to be at least 1 before the pipeline terminated).  It would be more efficient if there'd been someway to implement it to stop after that first one, but presumably the thinking was "if we're going to have to iterate once, we may as well iterate through all results for consistency for this use case" / something like that?

Comment: I think you mean `select -index 0`.

Comment: @js2010 `select -index 0` returns the first item in the list.  Here I was investigating what happens when you use `select -first $x` to terminate the pipeline early.  Where `$x >=1` then it terminates as you'd expect; but when `$x = 0` it runs for everything.  That would make sense if $x=0 was the default (like `-1` or `[Int64]::MaxValue` often are), but in that case you'd expect all rows to be output too; whereas in this case the pipeline isn't terminating, but we're also getting no output.

Comment: Oh ok, that's interesting.

Comment: Maybe you can filter it like this:  `echo 1,2,3 | foreach { if (!$requiredamount) { break }; $_ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-Object -First 0` or `Select-Object -Last 0`

Actually the cmdlets internally have a check for this exact scenario and intentionally outputs nothing.

the reason why you are seeing `I'm running!` for 100 times is Write-Verbose is in `Porcess()` block. All 100 items get processed and outputs nothing as the code internally skips on the check `$this.First != 0` then Skipp